# DevOps Containerized jenkins : can't access to docker volume /var/lib/docker/volumes inside jenkins pipeline at build stage

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a jenkins container, i ran this container using docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
 services:
  jenkins-service:

    build: 
      context: ./
    image: docker/jenkins-local
    ports: 
     - 8080:8080
     - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - jenkins_data_prod:/var/jenkins_home
      - jenkins_tmp_data_prod:/tmp
volumes:
  jenkins_data_prod:
  jenkins_tmp_data_prod:
```

and here is my dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

# Installation of docker
USER root
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

# Adding user jenkins in groupe "docker"
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

# Installation of docker-compose
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose


#USER jenkins
```

After that i ran jenkins using `docker-compose up --build` command

i first noticed that my docker is mounting volumes **"jenkins_jenkins_data_prod"**, and **"jenkins_jenkins_tmp_data_prod"** as name, while i was writing only **"jenkins_data_prod"** and **"jenkins_tmp_data_prod"** on my docker-compose.yml, so i modified my file and wrote volumes names as **"data_prod"** and **"tmp_data_prod"**

like this :

```
volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - data_prod:/var/jenkins_home
      - tmp_data_prod:/tmp
volumes:
  data_prod:
  tmp_data_prod:
```

i Found volumes mounted in "/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_data_prod/_data"
as "jenkins_data_prod" and "jenkins_tmp_data_prod" when i used to inspect the mountpoint using this command :

```
'docker volume inspect jenkins_data_prod'
```

Result command :

```
terminal :
 {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-06-15T23:33:41Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "jenkins",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.1",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "data_prod"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_data_prod/_data",
        "Name": "jenkins_data_prod",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
```

So after that i'm running a Jenkins pipline to build a personnal project on gitlab, it's using "/var/jenkins_home" as workspace

i have a docker-compose.yml file using bindmount volumes

My docker-compose to run

```
version: '3.3'
services:
 netcore:
   image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1
   volumes:
     - ../../projet-api/:/sources
     - ${NUGET_HOME}/.nuget/:/root/.nuget
     - ../build/netcore/application:/application
   working_dir: /sources
   command: dotnet publish -o /application -c Debug --self-contained false /p:Version=${VERSION}
```

when i run the image on "/var/jenkins_home" workspace i use to have error

```
+ docker-compose run --rm netcore
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```

so "/var/jenkins_home" was empty and my docker-compose only created folders with the name of "/projet-api" and "/build/netcore/application" i used to see where is the workspace containing the project i found it in "\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\jenkins_data_prod_data\workspace"

i looked arround docs and found that "\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes" was mapped to "/var/lib/docker/volumes/"

so i decided to try to run the image using environnement variables

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  netcore:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1
    volumes:
      - ${PWD_docker}/../../projet-api/:/sources
      - ${NUGET_HOME}/.nuget/:/root/.nuget
      - ${PWD_docker}/../build/netcore/application:/application
    working_dir: /sources
    command: dotnet publish -o /application -c Debug --self-contained false /p:Version=${VERSION}
```

My running part of jenkinsfile

```
node {
    
    //*********************************
    // getting code
    //*********************************
    stage ('SCM'){
        checkout scm
    }
    //*********************************
    // docker images
    //*********************************
     
     stage('RUNNING NETCORE') {
       
        dir ('project-docker/compile'){
            def containerPWD = pwd() // printing /var/jenkins_home/....
            def pwdval = "/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_data_prod/_data"
            def dockerHostPWD = containerPWD.replace("/var/jenkins_home", pwdval)//  /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_data_prod/_data
            
            def props = readProperties file: '.env'
            VERSION = props.VERSION 
            withEnv(["NUGET_HOME=${dockerHostPWD}","VERSION=${VERSION}","PWD_docker=${dockerHostPWD}"]) {  
               
                sh """   
                    docker-compose run --rm netcore                      
                """
            }
       }
    }
                                 .
        // rest of the code      .
                                 .
```

still same error of `MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.`

**Questions**

**1/** running my docker-compose using those paths only creating folders, at the last one i put it was in "\wsl$\Ubuntu\var\lib\docker\volumes" so looks like jenkins doesnt access to "\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes" which is the workspace containing the project, using path "/var/lib/docker/volumes" anyone can help me out finding how to access to volumes ?
Maybe "/var/lib/docker/volumes" is not really mapping to "\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes" ? but for "\wsl$\Ubuntu\var\lib\docker\volumes" ?

( without having to make symbolic link,or bindmounting my host "/var/jenkins_home" to jenkins "/var/jenkins_home" in the docker-compose that run jenkins.)

**2/** My second question is why i'm getting "jenkins_" prefixed to my volumes, we can see on labels "com.docker.compose.volume": "data_prod" and we see at the name  "Name": "jenkins_data_prod"
and why the label volume is "data_prod" and volume name isnt